# crystalReportViewer in windows application

Tags: c#, windows, crystal-reports

i'm using a code to send the ConnectionInfo to the crystalReportViewer

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "192.168.3.58";
        myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "SHRK-Traffic";
        myConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
        myConnectionInfo.Password = "pass";
        setDBLOGONforREPORT(myConnectionInfo);
        crystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
    }
    private void setDBLOGONforREPORT(ConnectionInfo myconnectioninfo)
    {
        TableLogOnInfos mytableloginfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        mytableloginfos = crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
        foreach (TableLogOnInfo myTableLogOnInfo in mytableloginfos)
        {
            myTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = myconnectioninfo;
        }
    }
```

i'm working with this code in web app  and it's working fine..but in windows app it show that error

[image: error]

i'm getting an error

Comment: i did it using anther way 



            Val objReport=new Val();
            objReport.SetDatabaseLogon("sa","Pass","192.168.3.58","SHRK-Traffic");
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objReport;

where "val" is the report name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a TableLogOnInfo object, then set it's ConnectionInfo object to the correct information i.e.:

```
        TableLogOnInfo loginDetails = new TableLogOnInfo();

        loginDetails.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "ALFA1\\ACMSDB";
        loginDetails.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "***";
        loginDetails.ConnectionInfo.Password = "***";
        loginDetails.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "database";
        loginDetails.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
```

Then go ahead and add that configured TableLogOnInfo object to your LogOnInfo collection:

```
         crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Add(loginDetails);
```